# Minor issue with two dimensional array

Tags: javascript

I hope you'll help me with this. I have the following piece of code:

```
var m = new Array([],[]);
var p=1; 
while(p<=20){
  x=formula.;
  y=formula.;
  m.push(x);
  m[p-1].push(y) //here spits and error - Uncaught Type Error: m[(p - 1)].push is not a function
  p++;
 ...
}
```

I have also tried `'m[p][0]=x'; 'm[p][1]=y;' but on m[p][0].`.. throws an error because the sector 0 was undefined or sth like this.

Comment: m is just an array with 2 empty arrays inside, so anything above m[1] will give error

Comment: I might help to tell us a bit about what you're trying to accomplish. What's the goal?

Comment: The two dimensional array you have created `m` only has two 'rows'.  You first must fill the array up with a number of empty arrays - more than just the two you have done in your code (the `new Array([],[])`).  You can achieve this with a simply for loop.  Also, try to avoid the `new Array(...)` syntax where possible (it is rarely needed) and instead opt for the `[...]` syntax.

Comment: i'm trying to create a two dimensional array and on the first row to push all the x-es on each loop and on row 1 to push all the y-s on a loop, until looping is finished.

Comment: As you are trying to push data into 20 arrays, you need 20 arrays: `var m = new Array([],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]);`.

Comment: similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/966225/how-can-i-create-a-two-dimensional-array-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var m = [];
var p=1; 
while(p<=20){
  x=formula;
  y=formula;
  m.push([x,y]);
  p++;
}
```

Notes:

1. Only rarely do you need `Array()`, use `[]` instead, shorter.
2. All arrays are single dimensional, but you can nest arrays
3. You can build an array from variables in place like `[x,y]`
4. The first calculation's x will be in `m[0][0]` and the first calculation's y will be in `m[0][1]`
5. This yields m=[[x1,y1],[x2,y2],[x3,y3],...]`

If instead you want `m=[[x1,x2,x3,...],[y1,y2,y3,...]]` that should be coded differently:

```
var xs=[],ys=[];
var p=1; 
while(p<=20){
  x=formula;
  y=formula;
  xs.push(x);
  ys.push(y);
  p++;
}

var m = [xs,ys];
```

Comment: I decided to use the first method you proposed. I hope it pushes well but when it comes up to reading the array it returns me one and the same values... See how I'm reading it: 

    'while(i<=m.length){
       xo=m[i][0];
       yo=m[i][1];'

Comment: @KDX2 That's too little to go on.  It could be several different things.  Perhaps try asking a new question.  That will attract new people to the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are trying to do something like this:

```
var m = new Array();
var p=1; 
while(p<=20){
  m.push([]) // we add an empty array to m so p-1 position exists
  m[p-1].push(p) // we add an element to m[p-1]
  p++;
}

console.log(m)
```

Comment: sth like this but where do we get and save x and y?

Comment: @KDX2 either change .push(p) for .push(x,y) or you can use an object and do .push({ x : x , y : y }) and then access like m[0].x, m[2].y